# Applications of Kneser graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question

Kneser's conjecture remained unsolved for over two decades and is now well known for its proofs using topological methods in combinatorics.

However, I am wondering why we are interested in Kneser graphs. Are there any interesting applications (perhaps computer science?) or properties that make them special? Where does the motivation stem from?

Comment: It is a very basic combinatorial structure: subsets of a set, and it codifies disjointness. Why wouldn't you be interested in it?!

Comment: I was hoping there would be a use other than it being a basic structure. Of course, not all maths needs application but in graph theory I always get the impression that everything should come in handy somewhere.

Comment: These graphs were handy in motivating​ a whole new part of combinatorics!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am interested! Could you perhaps give me a keyword as to which new part that was so I can read up on it?

Comment: Topological combinatorics.

Answer (score 1):

[Method ringing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_ringing).  Over at the demo [Kneser Graphs](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/KneserGraphs/), the permutation 13527486 is used to traverse one graph.  This is the same permutation used by the Central Council of Church Bell Ringers to traverse 8 bells, two at a time, no two rung twice in a row.  Dates back to 1650.